# Why do I have to keep restarting the spark services in between spark jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a single node cluster, and I'm running `spark` standalone mode (i.e. I am not using `yarn` and not using `mesos`).

Here is my problem:  I run a very simple job, and it works.  Then I run the exact same job again, and it just hangs for a long time.  I go to the spark web UI and I can see that it is under "Running Applications", and I see that I have Alive Workers, etc., and everything seems fine.  and I see "Memory in Use" is 14.6 GB total, and 14.0 GB used....which also should be fine.  disk usage is 70% when I do `df -h`.  the spark webUI reports me using I'm using 3 out of 4 cores...which also should be okay.  So, I'm having trouble figuring out what the issue is.

Here are the details about my machine:

- 4 cores
- 16 GB
- using pyspark version `1.6.1`

...and here is exactly what is in my s`spark-defaults.conf` file:

```
spark.driver.memory 3g
spark.history.ui.port=18081
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.executor.memory=14g
spark.executor.cores=3
spark.executor.instances=1
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout = 9000
spark.memory.fraction = 0.8
#spark.default.parallelism=3
spark.task.maxFailures = 1
```

Now, after I restart `spark-master` and `spark-worker` then suddenly everything works.

Why do I have to restart this in between every single job?

Comment: Why is your first job not completing?

Comment: In the question I say: "I run a very simple job, and it works".  the first job does complete, and then when I rerun it, it just hangs ...unless i restart all the services...does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Can you add this at the end of your job,

```
sc.stop
```

where `sc` is your `SparkContext`

Let me know if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: It didn't help.  Why would you expect this to help?  It doesn't get stuck at the very end of the job - it gets stuck somewhere in the middle.

Comment: sc.stop terminates your sparkcontext and thus releases any resources that may have been in use. If these resources are still in use, you may face the wait-ish state you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when I do these two things then it runs perfectly fine:

- turn off hadoop resource manager like `sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop`
- reduce the `spark.driver.memory` from 3g to 2g

Comment: False alarm - that actually did not permanently solve the issue.